# Use component children as function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component and I would like for its children to be a usable function. Much like Context.consumer, I would like to be able to do the following:

```
<MyComponent>
    {(x) => doSomething(x)}
</MyComponent>
```

and have it return some display accordingly.

How would I go about this?

For my use case, I would like MyComponent to render a list of objects. To determine how these objects are displayed, I would like the user to be able to map the object (x) to some display (doSomething(x)).

For example:

```
//My Component contains a list [1,2,3]
<MyComponent>
    {(number) => <div>Number: {number}</div>}
</MyComponent>
```

Should render

```
<div>Number: 1</div>
<div>Number: 2</div>
<div>Number: 3</div>
```

Comment: does doSomething return some tags or something? in that case you have to run the function

Comment: I've added an edit.

Comment: `{[1,2,3].map((number) => <div>Number: {number}</div>)}` is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

It is called **render prop**.

```
const MyComponent = ({children}) => {
    return children(...some value here)
}
```

children is a function that returns ReactNode

then you can use it like this

```
const MyComponent = ({children}) => {
    return children(1)
}

<MyComponent>
    {(number) => <div>Number: {number}</div>}
</MyComponent>
```

Output: <div>Number: 1</div>